# QR code decoding & encoding in an android application

Tags: android, qr-code

I am working with android API v2.2.
I want in my application i can work with QR reader. means in a button click it open the camera and can able to read QR code.
Is it possible generate QR code through application?
How can i work with these? I dont have any idea. 
Plz tell me what should used for this(is there any lib or api available for this) If yes then what should be the process.
Give me a sample example.

Thank you

Comment: try this also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+qr+code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the zxing library : http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Comment: I am not getting. if possible plz describe me

Comment: There is a tutorial in the wiki on how to get started : http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 1):

you can use either
zxing library : http://code.google.com/p/zxing/
or
ZBar bar code reader here http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/?source=dlp